# how do I copy data that is in adjacent cells once another cell says yes?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying to have information from two adjacent columns copy over once a different column says "yes"

```
Column B - IUT GAINING COMMAND
Column C - IST GAINING COMMAND
Column D - GAINING COMMAND
```

Column A I have conditions set to say "yes" once the date is passed.
Column B and C have drop downs to where they are going.
I want column D to copy the text that is in either B or C once Column A says "yes"

Comment: Just use an IF formula, in D1 =IF(A1="Yes";IF(B1<>"";B1;C1);"")

Comment: I ahve tried your formula and it is not recognizing B1 or C1 in the formula I think it is because of the semicolon. any suggestions?

Comment: I have also changed the semicolons to commas, and that didnt work. The formual I am working with right now off yours is =IF(A1="YES",AND(IF(B1<>"",B1:C1),"") Do I need to type individual formulas for every value inside the quotations?

Comment: @JACK you typed `B1:C1` and it should be `B1,C1`. Notice the comma. Also, depending on language settings, separator or arguments in Excel functions are semicolon or commas.

Comment: @exSnake Your comment is a valid answer. I would thumbs up if you post it

Comment: @JACK Your idea to introduce the AND() function isn't a good one. Just replace the semicolons in exSnake's formula with commas and read up on the syntax for the IF() statement if you have any more problems with this.

Answer (score 1):

Like i said in the comment you can use IF Formula.

=IF(A2="YES",IF(B2<>"",B2,C2),"")

Care about the parameters separator, it could be either **;** o **,** depending on your windows region setting

```
+---+-----+-------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
|   |  A  |      B      |      C      |                 D                 |
+---+-----+-------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
| 1 | YES | IUT GAINING |             | =IF(A1="YES",IF(B1<>"",B1,C1),"") |
| 2 | YES |             | IST GAINING | =IF(A2="YES",IF(B2<>"",B2,C2),"") |
+---+-----+-------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Result will be:

[image: Formula Result]

If this is not the result your are looking for, feel free to add an example of what you